# Request.Cookies is null ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have controller named **StoredProcedureController** and I have method **CheckStoredProceduresInPerPageFromCookie**:

```
public class StoredProcedureController : Controller
{
    private int StoredProceduresInPerPage = 20;

    public StoredProcedureController()
    {
        CheckStoredProceduresInPerPageFromCookie();
    }

    public void CheckStoredProceduresInPerPageFromCookie()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Request.Cookies!= null)//this throws NullReferenceException
                StoredProceduresInPerPage = int.Parse(Request.Cookies["stProcsInPerPage"].Value);
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpCookie stPages = new HttpCookie("stProcsInPerPage");
                stPages.Value = StoredProceduresInPerPage.ToString();
                stPages.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                Response.Cookies.Add(stPages);//this throws nullreference exception
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                TempData["ErrorMessage"] = exc.GetBaseException().Message;
            }
        }
    }

    [RoleAuthorization("Admin_And_User")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ListOfStoredProcedures(int page, string SearchedStoredProcedure = "", string SearchedDB = "")
    {
        if (Request.Cookies != null) 
            //I am getting here so there cookie isn't null
        ....
    }
    .....
}
```

My question is why in `CheckStoredProceduresInPerPageFromCookie` Request.Cookies is null and in `ListOfStoredProcedures` isn't null.
P.S Sorry if my formatting and question isn't perfect(it is my first question on stackoverflow)

Comment: How do you call those methods? Can you provide more information about that and, maybe, add both HTTP requests to the question.

Comment: CheckStoredProceduresInPerPageFromCookie method I am calling from constructor and ListOfStoredProcedures when I am going current URL

Comment: I will edit my question

Comment: So it is important from where I am calling CheckStoredProceduresInPerPageFromCookie method?

Comment: The problem is, that the `Request` object isn't yet initialized in the constructor of the controller. You need to have a web method to access `Cookies` of the request.

Comment: Yes, it matter.

Comment: Thank you for that answer @BorisVaskin Request.Cookies is absolutely different that javascript document.cookie now i see :/ When I am in different url  Request.Cookies["stProcsInPerPage"] is null. And I can set Cookie that i will able to get from any url of project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the moment of running constructor ControllerContext aren't initialized, so you can't get Request.Cookies. Instead you can override Controller.Initialize()

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
     base.Initialize(requestContext);
     CheckStoredProceduresInPerPageFromCookie();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I set cookie in mvc that will be available get from any place from my project? (like document.cookie in javascript)

Comment: @DVL you would have to create a service to do that. Plus it would be tightly coupled to HttpContext and only available during requests.

Comment: Ok thanks everyone. I think i will post a lot from now on Stackoverflow :))